# AssemblyInfo and accessing regular functions

Tags: .net, assemblyinfo

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2009")]
```

is it possible somehow to access functions like DateTime.Now.Year inside the AssemblyInfo class? so as to put in like

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  " + DateTime.Now.Year)]
```

Doing the above will give, DateTime does not exist in the current context

Comment: This is not possible.  Attribute values must be constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, no, but there are 2 options to access .NET functionality against your assembly file.

The easiest way to do your example would be to use the AssemblyInfo task from the [MSBuildExtensionPack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/66799).

Once you have that installed you can use all the methods in that Task, http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.4.0/index.html, such as the following:

```
    <Target Name="Version">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="$(SourcePath)\Code\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.DateAndTime TaskAction="Get" Format="yyyy">
        <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="MyStartTime"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.DateAndTime>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo ComVisible="false" AssemblyInfoFiles="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" AssemblyBuildNumberType="YearWeekDay" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday" AssemblyBuildNumber="4" AssemblyCopyright=" Foo Copyright $(MyStartTime)"/>
</Target>
```

The other option is to create a custom msbuild task on your own and expose additional functionality that way.